# PHP search and replace not working with file_put_contents

Tags: php

This must be a really simple issue but I've been trying for an hour to solve. I have the following code:

```
foreach (glob("*.txt") as $filename)
{
    $file = file_get_contents($filename);
    file_put_contents($filename, str_replace("google","yahoo",$file));
}
```

And the `test.txt` contents are:

```
Fusce condimentum aliquam velit nec suscipit. 
Cras dapibus libero id ante volutpat laoreet. 
Aliquam luctus erat eget orci egestas, id tincidunt leo aliquam. 
google
```

For some reason `google` never gets replaced by `yahoo`. My question is, how do I replace `google` with `yahoo`?

Thanks

Comment: It works when I try it.

Comment: How do you know the `glob` actually found and traversed any files? Have you tried raising the `error_reporting` level since something doesn't work?

Comment: Just tested and it works for me

Comment: Are you sure you're globbing in the correct directory?

Comment: yea, I'm pretty sure it's the correct directory. The php file is in the same folder as the txt files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you issue the php command from a different directory then your code can't find the file.

```
me@alfa:/tmp# cat test/test.txt 
Fusce condimentum aliquam velit nec suscipit. 
Cras dapibus libero id ante volutpat laoreet. 
Aliquam luctus erat eget orci egestas, id tincidunt leo aliquam.
google

me@alfa:/tmp# cat test/test.php 
<?php
foreach (glob("*.txt") as $filename)
{
    $file = file_get_contents($filename);
    file_put_contents($filename, str_replace("google","yahoo",$file));
}
?>

me@alfa:/tmp# php test/test.php 

me@alfa:/tmp# cat test/test.txt 
Fusce condimentum aliquam velit nec suscipit. 
Cras dapibus libero id ante volutpat laoreet. 
Aliquam luctus erat eget orci egestas, id tincidunt leo aliquam.
google
```

Changing directory to the location of the php and txt files makes it work.

```
me@alfa:/tmp# cd test/

me@alfa:/tmp/test# ls
test.php  test.txt

me@alfa:/tmp/test# cat test.txt 
Fusce condimentum aliquam velit nec suscipit. 
Cras dapibus libero id ante volutpat laoreet. 
Aliquam luctus erat eget orci egestas, id tincidunt leo aliquam.
google

me@alfa:/tmp/test# php test.php 

me@alfa:/tmp/test# cat test.txt 
Fusce condimentum aliquam velit nec suscipit. 
Cras dapibus libero id ante volutpat laoreet. 
Aliquam luctus erat eget orci egestas, id tincidunt leo aliquam.
yahoo
```